# VS2015 PerfTips Not Working

Tags: performance, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

I am running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I have tried without success to get the Perftips to appear while debugging. I have searched the internet for information and all I see are instructions on how to set the option which I have done numerous times.

Has anyone else had this problem and if so, what did you do to get them to appear?

Answer (score 7):

(1)Please make sure that the breakpoint was hit. For example, I just debug a simple Winform app, it works well.

[image]

(2)Navigate to Tools –> Options –-> Debugging  –> General, Checked the “Show elapsed time PerfTip while debugging”.

(3)Please use the latest VS2015 version with the update 3.

**Update:**

Discuss with Jack Welch, the solution is that we need to unchecked the option named " Use Managed Compatibility Mode" under Tools->Options->Debugging->General.

Comment: I am quite confident a breakpoint was hit. The option has been set, unset, reset, numerous times. I have VS2015 Update 3.

Comment: @Jack Welch, Could you share a screen shot about the result in your side? Please make sure that whether it is related to the color? http://dailydotnettips.com/2015/07/26/how-to-customize-perftips-color-in-visual-studio-2015/, or you installed certain add-ins which impacts this feature, you could disable them. Of course, if still no help, re-install the VS would be the suggestion I could think of. Hope it could help you.

Comment: @Jack Welch,  like the same issue here:https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6f9925bf-d450-4c58-b4d2-388c1d0dd466/perftips-in-vs2015-not-working?forum=vsdebug#a63d16b7-1aaa-438c-8fac-286c6e2ff4b1, I edit my answer? If it was resolved, would you please mark the answer? If not, please feel free to let me know:)

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks! Uncheked "Use Managed Compatibility Mode"